# wusa silent install error

Tags: powershell, updates

I am trying to automate updating Powershell on Windows 7 using Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu, and having a heck of a time. The following code works fine in a standalone ps1 file. And it works in my main ps1 file. But when run from a module it fails with exit code -2145124341. This is in PS v2, where negative exit codes are handled wrong, so that number is perhaps useless, and FWIW I have a good 40 other installers of various types that work from this module. However, this is my first attempt at automating msu files, so maybe there is a known interaction here that I haven't discovered yet? There's thousands of lines of code between the root ps1 file where this works and the module where it doesn't, so tracking down what is triggering the error is going to be a beast without some sort of trail to follow at the very least. So, anyone have an idea where I should start?

```
$filePath = 'wusa.exe'
$argumentList = '"\\PX_SERVER\Rollouts\Microsoft\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
$exitCode = (Start-Process -filePath:$filePath -argumentList:$argumentList -wait -errorAction:stop -passThru).exitCode
```

Also, running wusa.exe leaves some detritus in the script folder, but only when it is run from the module. Is this an issue with the msu file, or just a bug in wusa? Or does it point at what is causing the issue perhaps?
I had hoped to get this update to work to enable some new features, but between not being able to automate and garbage being left behind, I am very close to abandoning that path and juts continuing to target v2. But hopefully someone can point me in the right direction as that is not my preferred solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

a few toughts on first reading :

- The ArgumentList parameter for Start-process needs an ARRAY to work well :

  ```
  $argumentList =  @( "\\PX_SERVER\Rollouts\Microsoft\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu", "/quiet", "/norestart" )
  ```
- wusa.exe takes a log parameter : /log:c:\fso\install.log can you had it to your script for this particular package to check what happens ?
- a powershell script trying to update powershell ... I'm not quite sure this is meant to work ... it's the only case in wich i'll backup on another scrpting language (people, please correct me if i'm wrong ... )

Please let me know the result of the wusa.exe /log command, thanks

Comment: So, from the bottom... ;) I had worried about updating PS from PS as well, so I tried it in a script that did nothing else, and it seemed to work fine. Of course it needs a restart, but my full script manages that already, so I figured I was fine. As for the log, I forgot to mention, I did add the log option, and I get a log that is some sort of binary and utterly useless to me. I will look at the argument list as an array, but again, it works fine in a standalone script, and it works fine in the root ps1. It only fails when it's in a psm1 file, which is also when the leftover files show up.

Comment: I am looking now at the Location value for both conditions to see if maybe pushing and popping location may help. EDIT: Nope, Get-Location returns the same path in both cases. But failure in the module is 100% reproducible. Arg!

Comment: And I switched to an array of arguments, also to no avail. Non arrayed arguments work fine when the Start-Process code is in the ps1, so I am starting to think it has to be an issue with being in a module, and maybe a bug in v2. Frustrating.

Comment: On second reading : What are the detritus you're talking about on your first post ? if they come only when using the module, check that there's no commant output left unmanaged, like a line with simple string between quotes. on a script, they end up on the screen, on a module, it depends of your configuration ...  Also, when i'm using modules, I ofently have troubles with the SCOPE of my variables (a script scope won't get out of the module for example ...) Check it on your script ...